# как прописать Activity в AndroidManifest.xml программно?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Создаю проект, выбираю шаблон Add No Activity
По умолчанию создается файл манифеста

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.site.a1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Сам файл разметки **activity_main.xml** не создаю, создам программно в коде.

Создаю класс **MainActivity.java**

```
package ru.site.a1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 //метод создает корневой элемент
 private void funCreateLinearLayoutMain() {
  LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  final int activity_main = 100;
  linearLayout.setId(activity_main);
  linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  startActivity(intent);

  funCreateLinearLayoutMain();
 }
}
```

Приложение разумеется не работает, потому что не заполнен файл манифеста таким кодом

```
<activity
 android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Вопрос, как программно заполнить файл мнифеста и возможно ли это? Этот код не срабатывает.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Что бы изменить манифест программно нужно как минимум запуститься, а у Вас нет точки входа. И при изменении потребуется пересобрать и переустановить Ваше приложение. А что мешает прописать `Activity` заранее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Манифест (как и все ресурсы приложения) упаковываются в `apk` файл во время компиляции, т.е. вы не можете изменять его программно во время исполнения.

Вам надо добавить тег активити в манифест руками, до компиляции.

Comment: Спасибо Вам ЮрийСПб, теперь все понятно.

Comment: @Anton Но ещё бы не мешало перед этим исправить код в `onCreate` т.к в таком виде запуск MainActivity уйдет в рекурсию.